# Not able to receive response from server using react-native-tcp-socket

Tags: react-native, sockets, tcp

### Description

I am using react-native-tcp-socket to communicate with a server through my react-native app. When I am using `write()` to send data to a server. I am not getting response in the `data` event. Whereas, when I am using telnet to communicate from the server through terminal I am getting the response. Can someone please guide what I am doing wrong here, or suggest some other package for this.

### Steps to reproduce

code:

```js
 client = TcpSocket.createConnection(
        {
          port: 7070,
          host: 'priceserver.attache.app'
        },
        () => {
          // sending data to server
          client.write('GETQUOTES');
        },
      );
      // socket event for - connection established
      client.on('connect', (on) => {
        console.log('connected to', on);
      });

      // socket event for - data received
      client.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Data ==>', data.toString());
      });

      // socket event for - error occured
      client.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

      // socket event for - connection closed
      client.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Connection closed!');
      });
```

### Current behavior

all events except data are working

### Expected behavior

I should get data in the data event's callback

**Screenshots**
Here is a screenshot of terminal, in which I am getting response.
[image: Screenshot from 2021-01-15 12-23-15]

### Relevant information

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| OS | Ubuntu 20.04 |
| react-native | 0.63.2 |
| react-native-tcp-socket | ^4.5.5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just saw the question. Self answering for anyone that needs this.

I needed to add a carriage return at the end of every request I was sending to the server so it was like this

```
client.write('GETQUOTES\r');
```

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon this problem.